# X-Mouse Button Control, is it possible to map: hold right click + scroll down = ctrl + page down

Tags: mouse, button-remapping, xmouse

I would like to set X-Mouse Button Control, so it will detect that I'm holding down my RMB, and then it will send single CTRL + Page Down for every scroll down with mouse scroll.
I would appreciate any advices,
Best regards!

Comment: This mapping is problematic, since letting go of the RMB will activate the right-click context-menu.